# Is there any way to run XSLT and generate PDF online using Apache fop?

Tags: xml, xslt, pdf-generation, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo

I want to generate PDF online like [xslt tranformation](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net)

**INPUT XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<students>
    <student>
        <name>Amrendra Kumar</name>
        <class>BCA</class>
    </student>
    <student>
        <name>Sanjeev Kumar</name>
        <class>MCA</class>
    </student>
</students>
```

**XSLT to generate PDF:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="a">
                    <fo:region-body margin="1in"/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="a">
                <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                    <fo:block>
                        <fo:table border="1pt">
                            <fo:table-column column-number="1" column-width="180pt"/>
                            <fo:table-column column-number="2" column-width="300pt"/>
                            <fo:table-header>
                                <fo:table-row padding-top="0pt" padding-bottom="0pt">
                                    <fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:block font-family="TimesNewRoman" font-size="10pt"  space-before="4pt" text-align="left">
                                            <fo:inline font-weight="bold" font-size="12pt">Name</fo:inline>
                                        </fo:block>
                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                    <fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:block font-family="TimesNewRoman" font-size="10pt"  space-before="4pt" text-align="left">
                                            <fo:inline font-weight="bold" font-size="12pt">Class</fo:inline>
                                        </fo:block>
                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                </fo:table-row>
                            </fo:table-header>
                            <fo:table-body start-indent="0pt" end-indent="0pt">
                                <xsl:for-each select="students/student">
                                    <fo:table-row padding-top="0pt" padding-bottom="0pt">
                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                            <fo:block font-family="TimesNewRoman" font-size="10pt"  space-before="4pt" text-align="left">
                                                <fo:inline font-size="12pt">
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                                                </fo:inline>
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                            <fo:block font-family="TimesNewRoman" font-size="10pt"  space-before="4pt" text-align="left">
                                                <fo:inline font-size="12pt">
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="class"/>
                                                </fo:inline>
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                    </fo:table-row>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </fo:table-body>
                        </fo:table>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output:** need to generate PDF online

Comment: Well, for the original xsltransform the source adapted to use Saxon 9.8 HE is online at https://github.com/martin-honnen/XSLT-Tester/blob/master/app/controllers/Application.java#L116.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @sbo once you check this link you get to know my question. Here we can generate XML to HTML online editor, Now i am looking for any site which can give me fo PDF? https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bnnZWJ/1

Comment: @Amrendra check this site online FO PDF convert
http://www.utilities-online.info/foprender/#.XQSTBBYzaM8

Comment: @AmrendraKumar check this out https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/1.1/servlets.html

Comment: @AjeetSingh Thanks that's what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can generate the pdf from XML and XSL file using apache fop.

```
public void convertXmlToPdf(String xmlFilePath, String xslFilePath, String pdfFileDirectory) throws IOException {

        File xmlfile = new File(xmlFilePath);
        File xsltfile = new File(xslFilePath);
        File pdfDir = new File(pdfFileDirectory);
        pdfDir.mkdirs();
        File pdfFile = new File(pdfDir, "pdfFile.pdf");

        System.out.println(pdfFile.getAbsolutePath());

        final FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance(new File(".").toURI());
        FOUserAgent foUserAgent = fopFactory.newFOUserAgent();

        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(pdfFile);
        out = new java.io.BufferedOutputStream(out);

        try{
            Fop fop;
            fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, foUserAgent, out);

            TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(xsltfile));

            Source src = new StreamSource(xmlfile);

            Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());

            transformer.transform(src, res);

        }catch (FOPException | TransformerException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            out.close();
        }

        System.out.println("PDF generated successfully");

    }
```